# Paginate with FeatureTable widget?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using the FeatureTable widget to add a table to map app that I built in the 3.17 JS API. As it's currently set up, the table loads more content as you scroll. My trouble is that my table has tens of thousands of records and the user could effectively be scrolling forever. Is there a way to paginate the table to something like 1000 records per page? Something that looks like the attached image? Can anyone point me to a sample that I can look at that accomplishes this or suggest a methodology?

[image]

```
require([
        "esri/map",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/dijit/FeatureTable",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/ready",
        "dojo/on"
    ], function (
        Map, FeatureLayer, FeatureTable, dom, parser, ready, on
    ) {
        parser.parse();

    var mapMain = new Map("mapDiv", {
            basemap: "topo",
            center:  [-121, 38],
        zoom: 6,
    showLabels: true
        });

        var myTableLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://data.farwestern.com/arcgis/rest/services/scratch/test_SD_RelatedResources/MapServer/2", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    visible: true,
    outFields: ["*"]
    });

        mapMain.addLayer(myTableLayer);

        myFeatureTable = new FeatureTable({
    featureLayer : myTableLayer,
    outFields:  ["*"],
    map : mapMain,
    gridOptions: {
        allowSelectAll: true,
        allowTextSelection: true,
        selectionMode: "extended"
    },
        syncSelection : false,
    }, 'tableDiv');

        myFeatureTable.startup();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. See the `pagination` boolean and `pageSizeOptions`: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featuretable-amd.html#gridoptions

Comment: Thanks so much, Gavin. That was easier than I thought it was going to be. For anyone else interested, I found a good write up of dgrid pagination options here, once I knew what to look for. https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.4.2/doc/components/extensions/Pagination.md